# Split a string after every nth occurrence of a delimiter into separate columns using SQL and add default values as needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a few columns that have 3 different possible types of strings in it.

1. an empty string
2. a string with 1 number (ex: 2.05)
3. a string with 12 numbers ( ex:

`'1.01, 2.02, 3.03, 4.04, 5.05, 6.06, 7.07, 8.08, 9.09, 10.10, 11.11, 12.12'` )

With that 12 number string, I need to split on every 3rd occurence of a comma, and then insert these newly seperated strings into various columns in a different table.

```
COL 1:             COL 2:             COL 3:             COL 4: 
1.01, 2.02, 3.03 | 4.04, 5.05, 6.06 | 7.07, 8.08, 9.09 | 10.10, 11.11, 12.12
```

These columns also have default values that need to be added upon trying to do anything with the empty string or the 1 value string.

The one value string would be entered like so:

```
COL 1:                COL 2:    COL 3:    COL 4: 
0, 0, *some number* | 1, 0, 0 | 0, 1, 0 | 0, 0, 1
```

The empty string would just have 0 instead of that value.

That original column once all the data has been converted over and added properly will end up becoming a GUID with a reference key to the location of where I am inserting that into the other table after the split. I'm not really worried about that at the moment though.

Comment: Ouch. I think you've found a new worst case for the kind of string manipulation T-SQL is really uncomfortable with. Do you at least have SQL Server 2016, so you have `STRING_SPLIT`?

Comment: I would make a case that your third option is a really bad idea. Storing multiple values in a single tuple violates 1NF and is a real pain to deal with as you have found out. This should be normalized into something you can use instead of continuing the agony of poor design.

Comment: All numbers have the same amount of characters? If so you could split in columns by characters lengths. If not you will have to apply a string split function that gives you the order of the split by item, then group them in trios and format them. You should also separate the logic between your 3 different scenarios.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah I am working 2016. I tried just splitting the stuff with a STRING_SPLIT, but it wasnt actually splitting anything. Granted that could be partially due to my own limited understanding of SQL. I know enough to be dangerous, but not enough to be a real threat haha

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci Unfortunately the length of these numbers tends to vary quite a bit. They're essentually 4 different coordinate vectors, I just gotta split them up and put them elsewhere in the DB

Comment: An aside based on your last paragraph: You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows. `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`. A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Comment: @HABO The sounds incredibly useful! I'll have to take a look into that, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you are on 2016, another option is as follows

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,''),
(2,'1.01, 2.02, 3.03, 4.04, 5.05, 6.06, 7.07, 8.08, 9.09, 10.10, 11.11, 12.12'),
(3,'2.05')

Select A.ID
      ,Col1  = case when Pos2 is not null then concat(Pos1 ,', ',Pos2 ,', ',Pos3)  else concat('0, 0, ',case when Pos1 = '' then '0' else Pos1 end) end
      ,Col2  = case when Pos2 is not null then concat(Pos4 ,', ',Pos5 ,', ',Pos6)  else '1, 0 ,0' end
      ,Col3  = case when Pos2 is not null then concat(Pos7 ,', ',Pos7 ,', ',Pos9)  else '0, 1 ,0' end
      ,Col4  = case when Pos2 is not null then concat(Pos10,', ',Pos11,', ',Pos12) else '0, 0 ,1' end
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos10 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[10]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos11 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[11]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos12 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[12]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(A.SomeCol,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Col1                Col2                Col3                Col4
1   0, 0, 0             1, 0 ,0             0, 1 ,0             0, 0 ,1
2   1.01, 2.02, 3.03    4.04, 5.05, 6.06    7.07, 7.07, 9.09    10.10, 11.11, 12.12
3   0, 0, 2.05          1, 0 ,0             0, 1 ,0             0, 0 ,1
```

Comment: I had found something similar to this, but couldn't figure out how to do what you did with those column declarations, this does exactly what I needed almost entirely. I guess my next step then is to do an insert statement with this as the select, and build a cross reference table fro those GUIDs that are gonna be generated. Thanks, you really helped me out here!

Comment: @DanielB Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Your target format is better than the CSV strings, but still not the best. You should try to get this as row-by-row table out of which you can generate any output format easily.

This answer will provide a resultset with all the information you will need to get this in your groups (pivot or conditional aggregation):

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourStrangeString VARCHAR(150), DefaultValue VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 ('','abc')
,('2.05','xyz')
,('1.01, 2.02, 3.03, 4.04, 5.05, 6.06, 7.07, 8.08, 9.09, 10.10, 11.11, 12.12','blah');
```

--the query

```
WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT *
         ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourStrangeString,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Fragment
    FROM @mockupTable
)
,ToNumberedFragments AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS FragmentNmbr
          ,Frg.value('text()[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fragment
          ,DefaultValue
    FROM Splitted
    OUTER APPLY Fragment.nodes('/x') AS A(Frg)
)
SELECT ID
      ,FragmentNmbr
      ,(FragmentNmbr-1)/3 AS FragmentGroup
      ,Fragment
      ,DefaultValue
FROM ToNumberedFragments;
```

the result

```
ID  Nr  grp  nmbr   DefaultValue
1   1   0    NULL   abc
2   1   0    2.05   xyz
3   1   0    1.01   blah
3   2   0    2.02   blah
3   3   0    3.03   blah
3   4   1    4.04   blah
3   5   1    5.05   blah
3   6   1    6.06   blah
3   7   2    7.07   blah
3   8   2    8.08   blah
3   9   2    9.09   blah
3   10  3    10.10  blah
3   11  3    11.11  blah
3   12  3    12.12  blah
```

The grouping trick is integer division.

Now, seeing John's answer, I think this will be better for your needs...